# Related Product on Checkout Page

Tags: magento-1.8, onepage-checkout

Is it feasible and possible to add Related product section on Checkout Page?If yes,how can we add it so that customer can add product to cart from checkout page itself.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

see As per Magento Standard

`Related Product` Means This product recommendation is based on the product your customer is currently viewing and it intends to make customer buy more products including the one that he wanted in the first place. In this case, products usually come with checkbox to make it even more easier for customer to add items in the cart. Of course, if the product is configurable, checkbox cannot be used because the configurable attributes must be defined first.

That will be display on the product Detail page. That is related to that product only.

On cart page you can set the `Cross Sell` product.

you can display Cross Sell product On checkout page.